# How should I filter a set to another set in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to get to grips with Kotlin and functional programming and failing on a pretty simple exercise.

I'll modify this a little so as to make it not too obvious that it is from a specific online course but I'm just trying to get started really and not trying to fool anyone...

I am working with 2 collections

```
data class Pet(val name: String)

data class Household (
   val pet: Pet,
   ... 
)

data class District(
   val allPets: Set<Pet>,
   val allHouseholds: List<Household>,
   ...)
```

I want to find all pets not in a household.  It has to be returned as a Set
as I have been given this signature to play with

```
fun Locality.findFeralPets(): Set<Pet> =
```

I was going to do a filter operation but this returns a list and I can't see how to convert this to a set.  Can anyone point me in the right direction ?  It is very possible that filter is the wrong approach altogether!

```
allPets.filter { pet -> pet.name != "Bob" }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's more efficient to do this in a different way, avoiding a separate conversion:

```
allPets.filterTo(HashSet()) { pet -> pet.name != "Bob" }
```

Comment: Agreed, thanks @yole.  Had a look at the decompiled code to see what's happening under the hood and definitely looks more efficient the way you suggest.  This should be the accepted answer instead of my suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

`filter` returns an `Iterable` which has an extension method on it called `toSet` which returns a `Set`.  e.g.

`allPets.filter { pet -> pet.name != "Bob" }.toSet()`

Comment: ouch... ;-)  Thanks.